How to Get the Top-Most View Controller in iPad with Multiple Scenes (UIScene) in Swift?
I have an existing method to get the top-most view controller in iOS applications without multiple scenes, which works perfectly for single window applications on both iPhone and iPad:
extension UIApplication {

    // Get top most view controller in App.

    class func getTopMostViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter { $0.isKeyWindow }.first?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return getTopMostViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return getTopMostViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return getTopMostViewController(base: presented)
        }
        
        return base
    }
}

However, with the introduction of multiple scenes (UIScene) in iOS 13, I need a way to get the top-most view controller that can handle multiple windows and scenes. I adapted the function as follows:
extension UIApplication {
    
    class func getTopViewController(base: UIViewController? = keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        // Find the most visible view controller in the hierarchy
        
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return getTopViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return getTopViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return getTopViewController(base: presented)
        }
        
        return base
    }

    private static var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        // Get connected scenes
        return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            // Keep only active scenes, onscreen and visible to the user
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            // Keep only the first `UIWindowScene`
            .compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
            // Get its associated windows
            .flatMap { $0.windows }
            // Finally, keep only the key window
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }
    }
}

This works fine most of the time, but occasionally, keyWindow is nil on iPhone. I tried adding a 0.5 seconds delay and making the function asynchronous, which worked, but I want a synchronous solution that reliably works for both single and multiple scenes/windows.
How can I modify this function to always get the correct top-most view controller in a synchronous manner?
Additional Context:
I am targeting iOS 13 and above.
Note: First and foremost i want the second function to work on iPhone in every case currently when camera  permission dialog closes and i immediately call the second function on dialog's callback, then this issue occurs, where keywindow is nil.

First figure out why keyWindow is nil. Is there no scenes that are active? Or the active scene is not a window scene? Or there are no key windows? When exactly is "occasionally"? Under what circumstances would keyWindow be nil?

I just gave the exact (permission dialog) scenario in note, secondly, it does work asynchronously, when permission dialog callback is called and i introduce a delay before calling the top controller method.
